# Angular $resource calling error function on success call to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, resources, ngresource

Angular $resource is always calling error callback when calls are successful.  I have verified through Fiddler that the server is returning json with a success code of 200.  Keep in mind that this is happening in an Asp.net MVC view.  The return value from the restful call is a single object.

```
//Setup
$scope.targetResource = $resource(baseUrl + ":target", { target:    @target" });

// Triggering event
$scope.handleEvent = function() {
    $scope.targetResource.get({ target: "somevalue" },
        function() {
            // Never raises this function
        },
        function (responseError)
        {
            // Raises this function everytime with this response
            // {
            //    "data": null,
            //    "status": 0,
            //    "config": {
            //        "method": "GET",
            //        "transformRequest": [null],
            //        "transformResponse": [null],
            //        "url": "(the correct url)",
            //        "headers": {
            //            "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"
            //        }
            //    },
            //    "statusText":""
            //}
        }
    });
```

Am I missing something in my setup?  It is calling the correct method on the server and is passing the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

In that sample response you showed there there is a status of 0. Angular will not interpret a status code of 0 as a 'success'.

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success
>   status and will result in the success callback being called.

So in your server side code return a status code of 200, rather than 0.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem was I was making a cross domain call improperly.  MVC project to WebApi project without using JSONP.  I moved the call to the origin server and it now works without error.  Thank you Peter for helping out!